# Linux semaphores: spinlock or signals?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, semaphore

How does the current implementation of semaphores work? Does it use spinlocks or signals?

How does the scheduler know which one to invoke if signals are used?

Also how does it work in user space? Kernel locking recommends spinlocks but user space does not. So are the implementations different in user space and kernel space for semaphores?

Comment: If you notice on the right hand side when asking a question, you'll see that it says `Provide details. Share your research.`..Please do so, so that we know where you have looked, what you have found and assist you accordingly!

Comment: @user1761555 The question is more than enough details

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the power of Open Source - just look at source code.

The **kernel-space** semaphore is defined as

```
struct semaphore {
    raw_spinlock_t      lock;
    unsigned int        count;
    struct list_head    wait_list;
};
```

`lock` is used to protect `count` and `wait_list`.

All tasks waiting on a semaphore reside in `wait_list`. When the semaphore is upped, one tasks is woken up.

**User-space** semaphores should rely on semaphore-related system calls, Kernel provides. The definition of user-space semaphores is:

```
/* One semaphore structure for each semaphore in the system. */
struct sem {
    int              semval;      /* current value */
    int              sempid;      /* pid of last operation */
    spinlock_t       lock;        /* spinlock for fine-grained semtimedop */
    struct list_head sem_pending; /* pending single-sop operations */
};
```

The kernel uses definition of the user-space semaphore similar to the kernel-space one. `sem_pending` is a list of waiting process plus some additional info.

I should highlight again that neither kernel-space semaphore, nor user-space one uses spinlock to wait on lock. Spinlock is included in both structures only to protect structure members from the concurrent access. After the structure is modified, spinlock is released and the task rests in list until woken.

Furthermore, spinlocks are unsuitable to wait on some event from another thread. Before acquiring a spinlock, kernel disables preemption. So, in this case, on uniprocessor machines, spinlock will never be released.

I should also notice that user-space semaphores, while serving on behalf of user-space, are executing in kernel-space.

P.S. Source code for the kernel-space semaphore resides in [include/linux/semaphore.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/semaphore.h) and [kernel/semaphore.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/semaphore.c), for user-space one in [ipc/sem.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/ipc/sem.c)

Comment: My question is why it has spinlock rather than sleeping mechanism?

Comment: spinlock included only to protect `count` and `wait_list` and avoid race-conditions while editing them. After task added to `wait_list`, spinlock released and task rest in `wait_list` until woken.

Comment: Is there any implementation of semaphore in userspace and kernel space?

Comment: I've added details about the kernel implementation of user-space semaphores